# How can I switch logging on and off in tests using slf4j and Maven?

Tags: maven, slf4j

We're using slf4j along with a Maven build. When writing code we do not include a dependency to a slf4j implementation (such as logback), but only to slf4j itself.

In such a context when we run (unit) integration tests, slf4j falls back to a No-op implementation and all logs that the SUTs (systems under test) code produce are "ignored" as expected.

That's fine, however sometimes we need to display these SUT (debug) logs. Usually our developers add a dependency on logback with a `test` scope to achieve this and write logs to the console. I'm not a big fan of this approach, but as long as they do not forget to remove the dependency prior to committing code it's fine with me... However this switch on/off can occur multiple times and is thus error prone (and we end up with build logs being flooded).

Is there a better way to achieve this ? For instance leaving logback as a `test` scoped dependency all the time, but setting a property that would avoid logs to be generated unless the property is removed (some kind of "force No-Op" property) ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Let the logback test scoped dependencie
- add a logback-test.xml under the src/test/resources folder with a root log level set to NONE
- add the logback test file to .gitignore once commited (the dev will be able to set a custom log level without the risk to push the file mistakenly)

cf . https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

> If you are using Maven and if you place the logback-test.xml under the
>   src/test/resources folder, Maven will ensure that it won't be included
>   in the artifact produced. Thus, you can use a different configuration
>   file, namely logback-test.xml during testing, and another file,
>   namely, logback.xml, in production.

Comment: I wasn't thinking about using a `logback-test.xml` along with `.gitignore`. Nice and thanks !

Comment: all the pleasure is for me, thx to Essex Boy for fair play :)

Answer (score 1):

You could have 2 profiles

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>debug</id>
        …
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
             <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
             <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
              <version>1.1.7</version>
              <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        …
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>release</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        …
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>…</dependency>
        </dependencies>
        …
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then add a logback-test.xml to src/test/resources which will only be picked up for tests if the logback dependency is present in the pom and will not be written to any release jar/war.

Then for debug use :

```
mvn clean install -Dprofile=debug
```

Comment: I like @Gab answer better :)

Comment: same for me. Thanks for your suggestion, but I do not want to pollute our pom.xml files :-)